# Passing values to Pair in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I have a pair which is type of `String` and `String &`, may I pass the values to Pair as shown below

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string&> NamedNode;
voi main(){
std::string name = "name";
std::string * value = new std::string("value") ;
NamedNode(name,*value);}
```

When I pass values to Pair as shown above I got following errors:

> error C2529: '_Val2' : reference to reference is illegal  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility
>
> error C2665: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types  d:\jzon\sample.cpp

and below warning:

> Warning   1   warning C4181: qualifier applied to reference type; ignored c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\utility

I'm using C++98, Microsoft visual studio 2008, OS-windows XP

Comment: What did your compiler say? Spoiler: the answer is no.

Comment: You are passing a pointer to to a reference variable so no.  Also use [int main()](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#main-returns-int) not `void main()`

Comment: If you tried to compile it, you would have known the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No it's `*value`.

- The standard main in C++ is `int main()` when no interest in command line paramenters and `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` or `int main(int argc, char** argv)` when need process the parameters.

Code (tested in GCC 4.9.1 with C++11):

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string&> NamedNode;
int main() {
    std::string name = "name";
    std::string* value = new std::string("value");
    NamedNode a(name, *value);
    std::cout << a.first << " " << a.second << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The `&` operator mean `reference of` in this case of `std::string` you need to pass an `std::string` not `std::string*`

Hints: don't use **new** in `C++`, it's almost sure not needed and allow bad practice (ex: memory leaks when exceptions are throw, etc...), use instead std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr (C++11), or boost::shared_ptr and boost::scope_ptr (if C++11 not allowed).

Comment: After Manipulated my code as you said, i got following error                   error C2665: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types d:\jzon\sample.cpp 16

Answer (score 1):

I think that you mean the following typedef

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string *> NamedNode;

int main()
{
    std::string name = "name";
    std::string *value = new std::string( "value" ) ;
    auto p = NamedNode( name, value );
    delete value;
}
```

If you indeed mean

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string &> NamedNode;
```

then main will look like

```
int main()
{
    std::string name = "name";
    std::string *value = new std::string( "value" ) ;
    auto p = NamedNode( name, *value );
    delete value; // or delete p.second;
}
```

Here are two additional approaches

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

int main() 
{
    std::string name = "name";
    std::string *value = new std::string( "value" ) ;

    auto p = std::tie( name, *value );

    auto p1 = 
        std::make_pair( name, std::unique_ptr<std::string>( new std::string( "value" ) ) );

    delete value;

    return 0;
}
```